# Percentage growth between 2 values, SQL Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, percentage

```
SELECT numero AS Dormidas
FROM dormidas
WHERE numero = ((SELECT numero FROM dormidas 
                 WHERE ano = 2019 AND tipo = "hotel") / 
                (SELECT numero FROM dormidas 
                 WHERE ano = 2010 AND tipo = "hotel")) * 100.0; (not working)
```

The query is "show the percentage growth between the values of 2010 to 2019 from hotels.

This might not be the correct way to do the percentage growth between two values, but I have no idea on how to really progress.

The table I'm getting the values from has 3 colums: Ano - 1965 to 2019, tipo - hotel and the "numero" which has all the values.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

> how the percentage growth between the values of 2010 to 2019 from hotels.

Conditional aggregation is one way to do what you want:

```
select (sum(iif(ano = 2019, numero, 0)) * 100.0 /
        sum(iif(ano = 2010, numero, null))
       ) - 100 as percentage increase
from dormidas
where ano in (2010, 2019) and tipo = "hotel";
```